# Huge amount of logs have been missing when using async log

Tags: azure, azure-storage, nlog, azure-blob-storage, azure-diagnostics

I've enabled diagnostics logging to Blob Storage for an Azure Website I am trying on. I've also set `Nlog` to write to `Trace`, so that they are then in turn written to the Azure blob. This works, and the generated logs are outputted to the blob storage. Previously I used sync logging that wrote all log properly, but now I have changed it to `async` after that huge amount of logs have been missing.

```
<target name="asyncTrace" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" overflowAction="Block" queueLimit="200000" batchSize="1000" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0">
      <target xsi:type="Trace" name="trace" />
</target>
```

Another logging like Database logging works properly. I have not found any control over this.
Any idea if there is something to do about this?

Comment: Could you provide more details, Where did you change the option of async logging ? Is it within the WebApps or in the blobs level ? What kind of missing logs were you able to get if you compared them with the initial normal logging ?

Comment: Have you by accident added `async="true"` to the top `<targets>`-element? If so then it will by default discard when target cannot keep up.

Comment: Please check also the internal log for errors